# Why does my touchpad go crazy on Windows but not Linux?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-vista

I've had this problem on my laptop for sometime now. Anytime I try to use my touchpad it works correctly about 60% of the time in Windows, the other 40% of the time, it will jump to a random spot on the screen.

It has had this problem in Windows XP, Vista, and 7! I did clean installs of each OS. Now heres where it gets weird, when I switch to Ubuntu 9.04, my touchpad works fine 100% of the time.

Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: did you install the manufacturer's touchpad drivers or are you using the generic windows driver?

Comment: @Molly: Probably Windows, I'll have to check (not at my machine at the moment). I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems to come from the Synaptics Drivers. I installed the latest from thier website and it's still doing. I'm also looking for a solution. I'm on Windows 7 and my laptop is a Lenovo N100.

Comment: @Linvinloud: Try playing with the settings like ChrisF suggests. It won't stop it, but will minimize the frequency.

Comment: I tweaked my sensitivity in the Synaptics options, and it seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with the sensitivity settings of the touchpad. By that I mean how much pressure you need to exert for it to register a touch. I'm guessing that under Windows it's very sensitive & less so under Ubuntu.

Are there any settings for this in Windows? (I don't have a laptop to check myself).

Comment: I'm not at the machine currently but I check when I get home.

Comment: Well it minimized the frequency that it will jump, but it didn't totally stop it. I would say it does it 10% of the time now, which still pisses me of when it does it, but is acceptable since I only use the touchpad when traveling. So how about an accepted answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses entirely different drivers from the drivers on windows, so if there's a bug in the windows driver, it (likely) won't be present on Linux.  But yes, check your settings for sensitivity, acceleration, etc.